# c# html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack, pack

We are moving an e-commerce website to a new platform and because all of their pages are static html and they do not have all their product information in a database, we must scrape their current website for the product descriptions.

Here is one of the pages: http://www.cabinplace.com/accrugsbathblackbear.htm

What is the best was to get the description into a string? Should I use html agility pack? and if so how would this be done? as I am new to html agility pack and xhtml in general.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Agility Pack is a good library to use for this kind of work.

You did not indicate if *all* of the content is structured this way nor if you have already gotten the kind of fragment you posted from the HTML files, so it is difficult to advise further.

In general, if all pages are structured similarly, I would use an XPath expression to extract the paragraph and pick the `innerHtml` or `innerText` from each page.

Something like the following:

```
var description = htmlDoc.SelectNodes("p[@class='content_txt']")[0].innerText;
```

Comment: Ok here is what I am doing as of now:

string strHtml = wbOne.DocumentText;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(strHtml);
var description = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p[@class='content_txt']")[0].InnerText;

However I am receiving this error for the last line: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea on why this might be?

Comment: For the most part, all the pages are structured in the same way.

Comment: @Clay - the XPath is probably not returning any results. Try `"//p[@class='content_txt']"`, though this may return other rows as well. To be effective with the agility pack, I suggest brushing up on XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Also,

If you need a good tool for testing or finding the Xpath for the HAP you can use this one:
[HTML-Agility-xpath-finder](https://github.com/samfisher83/HTML-Agility-xpath-finder). It is made using the same library so if you find a xpath in this tool you be securely able to use in your code.