# looking for specific text and convert into link

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a bunch of html files (5000).

My business requirements defines a reference format, let's say it's XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ.

I want to replace, in all html files, any occurrence of such format by a link like this :

`<a href='~/app/document/XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ'>XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ</a>`

While it sounds "simple" using a standard regex replace, it's actually more difficult as I thought as the process can run multiple times.

My current process will "nest" the replacements to produces something like this :

`<a href='~/app/document/<a href='~/app/document/XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ>XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ</a>><a href='~/app/document/XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ>XXX-YY(Year)-ZZZ</a></a>`

How can I reach my goal ?

PS: performance is not an issue (at least when it stays reasonable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

check this one: [c# html agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143621/c-sharp-html-agility-pack) and plenty of other questions about it here in SO ;-)

this because you better to use a parser with solid understanding of the HTML tree, not just regex or text parsing which may fail depending on the specific markup...